# Figuring out cause of NullReferenceException when chaining methods, in debugging mode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

Let's say you have code like this:

```
Human mario = HumanFactory.CreateRandomHuman();

Console.WriteLine(mario.GetFamily().GetFather().GetEyeColor());
```

And let's say you run this in debugging mode, and it shows that line as getting a `System.NullReferenceException`, with the error message `'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'` But you don't actually know which object was null.

Is there a way to know which object actually caused the reference exception in Visual Studio? The debugger just shows the entire line as causing the exception, but you don't know if `mario` is null, or if `GetFamily()` returned null, or if `GetFather()` returned null, etc.

In the past I've just broken it up into individual lines and stepped through them until I got the null exception, but there's got to be an easier way to do it that doesn't involve breaking up the chain.

Comment: Hm, actually in VS 2017, the unhandled exception popup tells me which call returned null. That's handy! Let me check 2012... Nope, 2012 doesn't do that.

Comment: Select `Mario`, right-click, Quickwatch.  In the Quickwatch window, add `.GetFamily()` and reevaluate. Continue until you find the null.  Alternatively, rewrite temporarily until bug is found.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do it by pressing Shift-F9 after selecting part of the expression `Mario.GetFamily()`, or `Mario.GetFamily().GetFather()` etc.

But you have a bug in your code, so fix that first and things will be much easier:

- Either your GetXXX() methods are never supposed to return null, in which case at least one of them is not respecting this constraint.  Add a breakpoint in each method to find out which is the offending method, and fix it;
- Or there is no such guarantee, in which case your code above should be testing for null returned by each method.  If you are using C#6 there is a handy shortcut for this:

  ```
  mario.GetFamily()?.GetFather()?.GetEyeColor()
  ```

Answer (score 1):

When the exception is thrown in the IDE, use 'Quick Watch' (Shift-F9) on Mario.
In the Quickwatch window you can repeatedly build the chain and re-evaluate after each addition, to see when the null is returned.